# php MySql UPDATE not working?

Tags: php, forms

I have this form which contain dynamic table:

```
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction;?>" method="post" name="form1">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo (int) $_GET['a'];?>" name="pat_id">
<table>
<tr>
<th>#</th>
<th>ORDER DESC</th>
<th>STATUS</th>
<th>SENDING DATE</th>
<th>DELIVERING NO</th>
<th>DELIVERING DATE</th>
<th>COMMENT</th>
</tr>
<?php do { ?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $row_medi['order_no']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row_medi['ORDER_DESC']; ?></td>
  <td><select name="mydropdown[<?php echo $row_medi['order_no']; ?>]"><option value="Undelivered">Undelivered</option><option   value="Delivered">Delivered</option></select></td>
  <td><?php $sqldate=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($row_medi['SENDING_DATE']));
            echo $sqldate; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row_medi['DELIVERING_NO']; ?></td>
  <td><?php $sqldate=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($row_medi['DELIVERING_DATE']));
            echo $sqldate; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row_medi['COMMENT']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } while ($row_medi = mysql_fetch_assoc($medi)); ?>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
<input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1">
</form>
```

as you see there is a dropdown menu with each row and I want to update the hole row with selected value from any of this dropdown menu. There is no error msg appear but after clicking save button the selected row doesn't updated ?? this is UPDATE code:

```
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form1")) {
$pat_id = (int) $_POST['pat_id'];
$updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE orders SET STATUS=%s, pat_id=%s WHERE order_no=%s",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['mydropdown'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['pat_id'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['order_no'], "int"));

mysql_select_db($database_PPS, $PPS);
$Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $PPS) or die(mysql_error());

$updateGoTo = "Pharmacy.php?a=$pat_id";
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
$updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $updateGoTo));
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'update the hole row with selected value from any of this dropdown menu'? you have the same select name on each row, so $_REQUEST['mydropdown'] is the last row value for the dropdown??

Comment: also the value of selected option doesn't appear when I trying echo($choice)!!! how I can fix that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should check the whole code for security issues, but this could be done in a second step. Try to always use ints and cast the result as an expected int. For `$pat_id`, and on the view script instead of `<?php echo $_GET['a'];?>` do `<?php echo (int) $_GET['a'];?>`. But this is another problem.

`$pat_id` is not initialized on you server side code, but maybe you missed it in the copy/paste, else you'll need to do a:

```
$pat_id = (int) $_POST['pat_id'];
```

If I understand well you have several rows, each having a dropdown. You need to identify each dropdown with a distinct name for each row. So instead of :

```
<select name="mydropdown">
```

You should have

```
<select name="mydropdown[<?php echo $row_medi['order_no']; ?>]">
```

So that in each row you'll get something like:

```
<tr><td>42</td>(...)<select name="mydropdown[42]">(...)</tr>
<tr><td>43</td>(...)<select name="mydropdown[43]">(...)</tr>
```

And in the server side you'll get in `$_POST['mydropdown']` an **array** of values, with the order_no as index. Else `$_POST['mydropdown']` contains maybe the last select value only.
After that I do not understand exactly what want to do, but you may need to do several updates, one for each `order_no`.

**EDIT**:
This is your current lastest version of the code:

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form1")) { 
    mysql_select_db($database_PPS, $PPS);
    $pat_id = (int) $_POST['pat_id'];
    foreach ($_POST['mydropdown'] as $order_no => $choice) {
        $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE orders SET STATUS=%s, pat_id=%s WHERE order_no=%s", 
            GetSQLValueString($_POST['mydropdown'],"text"),
            GetSQLValueString($_POST['pat_id'], "int"),
            GetSQLValueString($_POST['order_no'],"int"));
        $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $PPS) or die(mysql_error()); 
    }
}
```

This is what I would write, now this does maybe not deserve a Stck Overflow question, maybe just read your code in a quiet envirronment and think carefully about what you want and what you have (use `print_r($_POST);die('aaarg');` to debug) :

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form1")) { 
    mysql_select_db($database_PPS, $PPS);
    $pat_id = (int) $_POST['pat_id'];
    foreach ($_POST['mydropdown'] as $order_no => $choice) {
        $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE orders SET STATUS=%s, pat_id=%s WHERE order_no=%s", 
            GetSQLValueString($choice,"text"),
            GetSQLValueString($pat_id, "int"),
            GetSQLValueString($order_no,"int"));
        $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $PPS) or die(mysql_error()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I edit the code as you mention. and what am trying to do is updating the row (which is already come from DB) with selected option from any of this drop down list.

Comment: @Abdulelah Al-Jeffery: what does "edit the the row with selected option from any" means? you want to catch that one row is selected? you want to make a random update? really I don't understand what you want

Comment: No it's simple just each row in the table which I retrieved from database contain this drodown list I want when the user select the option from any list in the table and clicking 'save' the changed row (that he select the option from) is updated. hope it's clear now :)

Comment: @Abdulelah Al-Jeffery: So now that you shoul dhave an array in `$_POST['mydropdown']`, make a foreach loop on that array, and if the value is "Delivered" then make the sql query, or maybe even if it's "Undelivered" -- depends on you -- but you now have several values so you need to perform several updates, loop on the result, isn't it? `foreach ($_POST['mydropdown'] as $order_no => $choice) { /* update or not */}`

Comment: this is the new code: if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form1")) {
 mysql_select_db($database_PPS, $PPS);
 $pat_id = (int) $_POST['pat_id'];
 foreach ($_POST['mydropdown'] as $order_no => $choice) {
   $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE orders SET STATUS=%s, pat_id=%s WHERE order_no=%s",                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['mydropdown'],"text"),
GetSQLValueString($_POST['pat_id'], "int"),
GetSQLValueString($_POST['order_no'],"int"));
$Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $PPS) or die(mysql_error());
}

Comment: Thank you very much regilero and I apologise for annoying you I think you are right I need some quiet and focusing more. Thanx again.